# Complex analysis... I can't write the function $f(z) =\tan (z)$ as a real part and imaginary part

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

> How to write the function $f(z) =\tan (z)$ as a real part and imaginary part?

I have reached the form :
\begin{align}
\tan (z) &= \frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}\\  
&= \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{ i (e^{iz}+ e^{-iz})}
\end{align}

Comment: I'm a new user & I have not read all question below... sorry!

Answer (score 3):

If $x,y\in\mathbb R$, then\begin{align}\tan(x+yi)&=\frac{\tan(x)+\tan(yi)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(yi)}\\&=\frac{\tan(x)+i\tanh(y)}{1-i\tan(x)\tanh(y)}\\&=\frac{\bigl(\tan(x)+i\tanh(y)\bigr)\bigl(1+i\tan(x)\tanh(y)\bigr)}{1+\tan^2(x)\tanh^2(y)}.\end{align}Can you do the rest?

Comment: I don't understand what did you do ..!

Comment: Can you interpret more than above?

Comment: It's up to you to tell me what is it that you don't understand.

Comment: At the first step ; how do you divide by (1-tan(x) tan (iy)) ?

Comment: I'm just using the formula$$\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}.$$

Comment: Ok; done for it... but my question is about how to fit the equation at the form : Re(z) + Im(z) not answered yet

Comment: @MomenNawafleh. Expand José Carlos Santos's result.

Comment: The last expression that I wrote is equal to$$\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(x)\tanh^2(y)}{1+\tan^2(x)\tanh^2(y)}+\frac{\tan^2(x)\tanh(y)+\tanh(y)}{1+\tan^2(x)\tanh^2(y)}i.$$

Comment: Oh ! Ok.. thank you for your reply 

Comment: The last question.. I need a programme to use it on my phone to write the equation as the form you do ?

Comment: No. I could do it on my phone if I wanted to, without any extra app. All I do is to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Oops ..  I can't do the same by my smart phone.. thank you ☺

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: @MomenNawafleh You only need to type the formulas enclosed in $ signs. The website replaces the content with the image of the formula. For example, if you type `$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$`, it will get replaced by $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$